# Setting the height of a slider

Tags: xcode

in Xcode, using the Attributes inspector, and working with a slider in the XIB file design tool, is it possible to set the height of the slider?  If it can be done, I can't seem to find it.

Comment: `UISlider`? `NSSlider`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to do it using the Attributes inspector. However you can programically customize the `UISlider`.

Here are the details: Develope.Apple: [Changing the Slider’s Appearance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006798-CH3-SW21)